# How to set min and max value for slider in croppie Js library

Tags: jquery, croppie

I set the scalezoom to 0.5,but it not working.
I want to set min  and max zoom scale for slider

should not zoom in less than min value and should not zoom out than max value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this issue by setting min and max value in Jquery
I changed the attribute value in Jquery
check this link

https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/232#issuecomment-484794189